# Solve $40x + 13\equiv 78 \pmod {105}$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Solve  $40x + 13\equiv 78 \pmod {105}$.

Having a bit of trouble with this problem, I have done other conditional congruence problems but can't quite solve this one. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Our congruence is equivalent to
$$40x\equiv 65\pmod{105},$$
which is equivalent to 
$$8x\equiv 13\pmod{21},$$
which is equivalent to
$$8x\equiv -8\pmod{21},$$
which is equivalent to
$$x\equiv -1\pmod{21}.$$
If we want to give the answer modulo $105$, the solutions are 
$x\equiv 20\pmod{105}$, $x\equiv 41\pmod{105}$, $x\equiv 62\pmod{105}$, $x\equiv 83\pmod{105}$, and $x\equiv 104\pmod{105}$.

I prefer to give the answer modulo $21$. Less typing.

Comment: To clarify for OP: $40x\equiv 65 \pmod {105}$ means that $40x=105k+65$, note that this is divisible by $5$, and we do this to obtain $8x=21k+13$, that is $8x\equiv 13\pmod {21}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$40x+13\equiv 78\pmod{105}$$

$$\iff 40x\equiv 65\equiv -40\pmod{105}$$

$$\stackrel{:40}\iff x\equiv -1\pmod{\frac{105}{\gcd(105,40)}=21}$$